# How to run simple jQuery AJAX calls in parallel in Symfony / Twig?

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, asynchronous

I wonder why my `jQuery` `$ajax(...)` calls do not run in parallel. The following code is used within a Symfony 2.8 project:

```
// Simple Controller to handle the request...
class TestController extends Controller {
    public function testOneAction() {
        $this->log('Test 1 started');
        sleep(10);
        $this->log('Test 1 complete');
        return new Response('TestOne', Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

    public function testTwoAction() {
        $this->log('Test 2 started');
        sleep(5);
        $this->log('Test 2 complete');
        return new Response('TestTwo', Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}


// jQuery whin Twig Template of TestPage
...
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        $.ajax({
            url : '{{ path('route_testone') }}',
            type : "post",
            data : 'test1',
            dataType : "text",
            context : this,
            success : function(data) {
                console.log('Test 1 Success: ' + data);

                var end = new Date().getTime();
                console.log('   ' + (end - start));
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url : '{{ path('app_testtwo') }}',
            type : "post",
            data : 'test2',
            dataType : "text",
            context : this,
            success : function(data) {
                console.log('Test 2 Success: ' + data);

                var end = new Date().getTime();
                console.log('   ' + (end - start));
            }
        });

        console.log('Ajax fired');
    });
</script>
```

**I would expect the following result:** Request 1 is started and request 2 is started. Request 2 is the first to complete after 5 seconds and request 1 follows after 10 seconds **in total**.

```
// JS console:
Ajax fired
Test 2 Success: TestTwo
    5288
Test 1 Success: TestOne
    10515

// Symfony log:
Test 1 started
Test 2 started
Test 2 complete
Test 1 complete
```

**Instead I get the following result:** The order of the two requests is random. Which ever request starts first also completes first. The total runtime is the **SUM** of the two calls, about 15 seconds.

```
// JS console:
Ajax fired
Test 1 Success: TestOne
    10413
Test 1 Success: TestTwo
    15897

// Symfony log:
Test 1 started
Test 1 complete
Test 2 started
Test 2 complete
```

This means that the two requests are not handeled in parallel but sequentially. This is confusing since regarding to the jQuery Docs AJAX calls should be handeled asynchronously by default:

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

I neither use `async:false` nor `dataType: "jsonp"` and do not perform cross-domain requests.

**So why are these calls not handled in parallel?**

Comment: because you use php with one Thread